# Live Wallpaper onTouchEvent ACTION_DOWN only play 1/3 of a sound clip

Tags: touch-event, live-wallpaper, audio

I just made a Fish Aquarium Live Wallpaper and wanted to add a sound effect when user touches a moving fish.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how to make it because only one third of the sound clip was played.  Grateful if some experts can help.  Here below are my code:

```
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

Region region1 = new Region(image1x, image1y, image1x+image1.getWidth(),
image1y+image1.getHeight());


if(region1.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
{image1x=(int) (event.getX()+60);   

MediaPlayer myplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.hi);
myplayer.setVolume(100, 100);

myplayer.start();               
}

Region region2 = new Region(image2x, image2y,
image2x+image2.getWidth(),image2y+image2.getHeight());

if(region2.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
{

image2x=(int) (event.getX()-100);

} super.onTouchEvent(event);


  return;
}           

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create your MediaPlayer in the on Touch Method, its better to declare a MediaPlayer field, and create it only once in your WallpaperService onCreate() Method like this :

```
private MediaPlayer myPlayer;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
        R.raw.hi);                    
}
```

// then in your onTouch Method you start the sound :

```
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

// ...

myPlayer.start();
}
```

// that should work and also save resources.